# Use Lightning Calendar in Home Page

Tags: lightning-aura-components, home-page-component, calendar

We are using Lightning based Calendar to see the tasks based on defined filters.We are planning to merge this with the Lightning home page, as currently, we are having a different page to see this.

Is there any option to bring this Calendar component into home page?

Comment: Hi there. Have you tried to expose Lightning based Calendar as a component which implements interface `flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes` and then drag it in Lightning App Builder to some region in your Lightning Home Page layout?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to expose Lightning based Calendar as a custom component which implements interface `flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes` and then drag it in Lightning App Builder to some region in your Lightning Home Page layout. This should work.